# CIDR notation and IP range validator pattern

Tags: java, regex, ip, cidr

I have a pattern to validate normal IP addresses, that is :

```
private static final String PATTERN =
            "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
```

And a validate method to check if the input is a valid IP address or not :

```
private static boolean validate(final String ip){

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

But, now I need to add validation for CIDR  (e.g. 84.240.40.0/24) notation and IP-range without host  (e.g. 172.24.105), I tried many different patterns but not getting something concrete. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+regex)? The first few results are what you want.

Comment: I have tried that, but I am not able to combine my regex for normal IP address check to CIDR and IP without host name.

Comment: You didn't look very hard. The second regex on the [first result](http://blog.markhatton.co.uk/2011/03/15/regular-expressions-for-ip-addresses-cidr-ranges-and-hostnames/) is for an IPv4 CIDR range (eg `192.168.1.20/24`).  Consider trying to *understand* the regexes instead of just copy/pasting them from wherever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\\/(\\d|[1-2]\\d|3[0-2]))?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("84.240.40.0/24");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
84.240.40.0/24
```

this pattern matches  IPv4 address and IPv4 CIDR range if you want tomatch only range ,you should remove last question mark